# Ajax Calendar Control within usercontrol is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

I'm using a Ajax Calendar Control within a usercontrol and for one page that references the calender it works fine but for the other page although i can t see any different references or anything when i click on the calender text box the calender does not pop up.

Here is some of the code let me know if you need to see more:

Inside the usercontrol:

```
<td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartFrom" runat="server" Width="80" MaxLength="10" />
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calDateTo" runat="server" Animated="true" TargetControlID="txtStartFrom"
            Format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValStartFrom" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStartFrom" ErrorMessage="You must enter a start date" CssClass="errorinputleftred" />
        <Opal:DateValidator ID="dValCalendar" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStartFrom"
            Display="dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid date" SetFocusOnError="True" CssClass="errorinputleft" />
    </td>
```

Page that refers to the control:

```
<%@ Register Src="RecurrenceControl.ascx" TagName="Recurrence" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<div...>
    <uc:Recurrence ID="ucRecurrence" runat="server" />  
</div>
```

Edited: jobAssign.ascx

```
    <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="JobAssign.ascx.vb" Inherits="HelpDeskWebsite.JobAssign" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Opal" Namespace="Opal.CustomWebControls" Assembly="Opal.CustomWebControls" %>
<%@ Register Src="RecurrenceControl.ascx" TagName="Recurrence" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<script type="text/javascript">

        // function for custom validator to check whether one of the boxes is checked.
    function validateCheckboxes(sender, args) {
        if (document.getElementById('<% = rbOpsJobs.ClientID %>').checked == true || document.getElementById('<% = rbOpsProject.ClientID %>').checked == true || document.getElementById('<% = rbOpsWish.ClientID %>').checked == true) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('<% = rbOpsJobs.ClientID %>').Visibility == 'hidden' && document.getElementById('<% = rbOpsProject.ClientID %>').visibility == 'hidden' && document.getElementById('<% = rbOpsWish.ClientID %>').visibility == 'hidden') {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="helptext">
    <% = HelpText %>
</div>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="upProcessing" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="floatProgress">
            <img id="imgProgress" src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Processing" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upJobAssign" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostbackTrigger ControlID="imgbtnAllocate"></asp:PostbackTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>

        <div id ="divResetRecurringJobs" class="divResetRecurringJobs" runat="server">

                <uc:Recurrence ID="ucRecurrence" runat="server" />             
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgUpdateRecurrence" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/buttons/allocate.jpg" ImageAlign="Right" />

        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="aeJobAssign" runat="server" TargetControlID="upJobAssign">
    <Animations>
        <OnUpdating>
            <Parallel Duration=".2" Fpt="30">
                <EnableAction enabled="false"/>
                <FadeOut Duration=".2" Fps="20" MinimumOpacity="0.3" />          
            </Parallel>
        </OnUpdating>     
        <OnUpdated>
            <Parallel Duration=".2" Fpt="30">
                <FadeIn Duration=".2" Fps="20" MinimumOpacity="0.3"/>
                <EnableAction enabled="true"/>
            </Parallel>
        </OnUpdated>
    </Animations>
</ajaxToolkit:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvSelectOneCheckbox" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateCheckboxes" ErrorMessage="You must select a job type."></asp:CustomValidator>
```

RecurrenceControl.ascx (where the calender is)

```
       <%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="RecurrenceControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="HelpDeskWebsite.RecurrenceControl" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Opal" Namespace="Opal.CustomWebControls" Assembly="Opal.CustomWebControls" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/webparts/SearchUsers.ascx" TagName="SearchUsers" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">function validateRecurrenceInformation(sender, args)
{
    var checkBoxList = document.getElementById ('<%= cblweekday.ClientID %>');
    var checkBoxes = checkBoxList.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (document.getElementById('<% = rbdaily1.ClientID %>').checked == true && document.getElementById('<% = txtEveryNumberOfDays.ClientID %>').value == '') 
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } 

        else if (document.getElementById('<% = rbYearly1.ClientID %>').checked == true && document.getElementById('<% = txtDayOfYear.ClientID %>').value == '') 
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } 
        else if (document.getElementById('<% = rbWeekly1.ClientID %>').checked == true) 
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length - 1; i++) 
            {
                if (checkBoxes[i].checked == true && document.getElementById('<% = txtEveryWeeks.ClientID %>').value != '') 
                {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                }
            }
        } 
        else if (document.getElementById('<% = rbdaily1.ClientID %>').checked == false && document.getElementById('<% = rbdaily2.ClientID %>').checked == false && document.getElementById('<% = rbweekly1.ClientID %>').checked == false && document.getElementById('<% = rbmonthly1.ClientID %>').checked == false && document.getElementById('<% = rbyearly1.ClientID %>').checked == false && document.getElementById('<% = rbMonthly2.ClientID %>').checked == false && document.getElementById('<% = rbMonthly3.ClientID %>').checked == false) 
        {
            args.IsValid = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
}
</script>
<div class="divQuestionText">
    Please select the recurrence options you require for this request.</div>
<table id="tblRecurrence" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="title">
            Start:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartFrom" runat="server" Width="80" MaxLength="10" />
            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calDateTo" runat="server" Animated="true" TargetControlID="txtStartFrom"
                Format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValStartFrom" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStartFrom" ErrorMessage="You must enter a start date" CssClass="errorinputleftred" />
            <Opal:DateValidator ID="dValCalendar" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStartFrom"
                Display="dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid date" SetFocusOnError="True" CssClass="errorinputleft" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="split">
        <td class="title">
            Daily</td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbDaily1" GroupName="grpRecurr" runat="server" />Every
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEveryNumberOfDays" Width="20" runat="server" />
            day(s)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbDaily2" GroupName="grpRecurr" runat="server" />Every Workday
            (Mon - Fri)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="split">
        <td class="title">
            Weekly</td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbWeekly1" GroupName="grpRecurr" runat="server" />Recur every
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEveryWeeks" Width="20" runat="server" />
            week(s) on:<br />
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblWeekday" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Monday" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Tuesday" Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Wednesday" Value="4" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Thursday" Value="16" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Friday" Value="32" />
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="split">
        <td class="title">
            Monthly</td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbMonthly1" GroupName="grpRecurr" runat="server" />
           <%-- Day
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDay" Width="20" runat="server" />--%>
           Recur every 
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAmountMonths" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="9" Value="9" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="11" Value="11" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="12" Value="12" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
            month(s).
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title"></td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbMonthly3" GroupName="grpRecurr" runat="server" />
            First day of the month
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title"></td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbMonthly2" GroupName="grpRecurr" runat="server" />
            Last working day of the month
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="split">
        <td class="title">
            Yearly</td>
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbYearly1" GroupName="grpRecurr" runat="server" />
            Every
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDayOfYear" Width="20" runat="server" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonths" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="January" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="February" Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="March" Value="3" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="April" Value="4" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="May" Value="5" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="June" Value="6" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="July" Value="7" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="August" Value="8" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="September" Value="9" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="October" Value="10" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="November" Value="11" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="December" Value="12" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
            Set time period
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYearAmount" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Every Year" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Every 2 Years" Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Every 3 Years" Value="3" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="split">
    <td class="title">Self Assign</td>
    <td><asp:CheckBox id="chkselfAssign" runat="server" /></td></tr>
        <tr class="split">
        <td class="title">
            End On:</td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndOn" runat="server" Width="80" MaxLength="10" CausesValidation="true"
                AutoPostBack="true" />
            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" Animated="true" TargetControlID="txtEndOn"
                Format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
            <Opal:DateValidator ID="DateValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEndOn"
                Display="dynamic" ErrorMessage="Invalid date" SetFocusOnError="True" CssClass="errorinputleft" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRecurrenceCheck" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="validateRecurrenceInformation" ErrorMessage="Please enter the correct recurrence ticket information for your specific choice"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Edit for comment below about form tag

the form tag is inside another .aspx page which calls the jobdetails.ascx page as so

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="screenScrapeAssign.aspx.vb" Inherits="HelpDeskWebsite.screenScrapeAssign" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/webparts/JobDetails.ascx" TagName="JobDetails" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:1137/email/screenscrapemail.css" />
<form id=ssform runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smMaster" runat="server"/>
<uc:JobDetails ID="ucJobDetails" runat="server" Title="Request Details" TitleIconImageUrl="~/images/icons/ticketdetails.jpg" />
 </form>
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `ToolkitScriptManager` (or possible a regular `ScriptManager` would work) on both pages?

Comment: Did you register the ajax control toolkit in the user control? Does your page or parent page have a script manager on it?

Comment: There doesn t seem to be one on either pages - even the one that works it is in the web.config under controls

Comment: Please post the markup for both the user control and the containing page so that we can see how the two work together. It would help to see the directive section. You will need a scrip manager for the ajax control toolkit to work properly.

Comment: sorry there is a script manager it is just higher up in the master page

Comment: Anna, are you using an ajax control toolkit script manager or a straight .net script manager?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

weirdly it has just started to work even though i haven t added anything to it - it seems that their was a problem with all the calender controls on that page - but they were working in live - so maybe a visual studio issue - and now for whatever reason they all seem to be working - including the ones in my usercontrol which weren t working before - thankyou for everyones help though.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. I don't see a `<form>` tag encapsulating everything and I don't see a ajaxcontroltoolkit script manager. Because you're using the toolkit you wouldn't use the default .net script manager. It acts quirky with the toolkit.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tsmMaster" runat="server" />
```

This should be located just inside your `<form>` tag.

Please note that the reason my version of the toolkit script manager has an asp prefix is because I set it up that way.

example:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Comment: please see my edit to the original post - i have tried adding your toolkit script manager to the form but it doesn t make a difference